# Are there any cheap tools available for printing custom vinyl stickers?

Tags: printing

I'm looking for a way to print my own custom vinyl stickers at home and don't want to spend the money for an expensive printer exclusively for printing on vinyl.

Are there other solutions for printing vinyl stickers that don't require purchasing a specific printer?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here unfortunately.. If you just want to cut the stickers, I think googling "die-cutting machine" will get you some good options. I don't know about printing on top of vinyl though.

Comment: @whrrgarbl I suppose it's not so much a specific product I'm looking for but a type of product or methodology

Comment: You can get laser printable vinyl sheet (I've used white, I think clear is also available) and use that in an normal laser printer. It cuts cleanly with scissor or a knife. It probably isn't as durable a more expensive solutions but you don't say whether this is for something permanent or temporary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your definition of cheap, but the Silhouette Cameo vinyl cutter allows you to replace the cutting blade with a colored marker so that instead of cutting the vinyl, you end up drawing on it with computer precision.

Alternatively, you can feed the vinyl sheets which are made for that cutter through an inkjet to get some image on it and then after it dries, coat it in a light layer of clear coat spray paint to keep it from smearing.